# How to get nearby wifi MAC address and signal strength using HTML5?

Tags: html, google-maps, google-chrome, web, geolocation

As we all know. We can locate ourself using Google Map in Chrome browser.

I want to know how it works. So I open Fiddler to analyze the packets.

I find that Google Map send nearby wifi MAC addresses and signal strength to their server, then return our location.

My question is, what the API Google Map use, to got those wifi information?

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=AIzaSyBOti4mM-6x9WDnZIjIeyEU21OpBXqWBgw HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 342
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

{
    "wifiAccessPoints": [
        {
            "age": 0,
            "macAddress": "aa-bb-cc-dd-ee-ff",
            "signalStrength": -54
        },
        {
            "age": 0,
            "macAddress": "11-22-33-44-55-66",
            "signalStrength": -79
        },
        {
            "age": 0,
            "macAddress": "66-55-44-33-22-11",
            "signalStrength": -84
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, Google has a database of Wifi MAC address and its location collected through multiple approaches with consent of users.

Based on the MAC addresses and strength you provided, Google can estimate your location using triangulation.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But that's how wifi to location. Not how to get wifi mac address.

Comment: You need OS level API in order to access the Wifi MAC address.

Comment: the word "consent" is doing a lot of heavy lifting for google

Answer (score 0):

Google drove around most of the world with google street view cars, collecting all the mac addresses of wifi routers it drove past. Google aggregated all these mac addresses and the precise location as well as signal strength data into a big database which people can now access using the Google Geolocation API.

When you want google to tell you your current location, you either send them just the mac address of your home wifi router, or like in the example you showed, your phone measures the signal strength to nearby wifi routers and sends that plus the respective mac addresses to google, who then look into their database and return a set of coordinates to you.

Other ways Google has *probably* gained this information is by doing this exact request in the background many many times on all android phones they have access to, and adding that to their database. 
 All with "users consent".